# Will Asteroid (2021 LD6) be visible to the naked eye?

Tags: amateur-observing, asteroids, naked-eye

There's a lot of hoopla online about asteroid 2021 LD6's  close approach to Earth. Will be close enough and large enough to be seen with the naked eye?

PS: More on the object:  [MPC](https://minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?object_id=K21L06D) or [JPL](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=K21L06D)

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE. Would be great if you could specify the "hoopla"...

Comment: By "hoopla" I mean "media attention." Sounds like it's overblown, like many things.

Comment: I understood that you are talking about media attention, but the point is that I do not find much media attention on the web, that's why I would appreciate a link or two.

Comment: @uhoh Have you heard about it in non-nerd media?

Comment: @B--rian There was a Jun 14 tweet prematurely noting a possible impact 58 years later. I'd rather not boost it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, at its brightest in June 2021, 2021 LD6 [[MPC](https://minorplanetcenter.net/db_search/show_object?object_id=K21L06D), [JPL](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=K21L06D)] was apparent magnitude 20-21, well beyond the reach of most amateur telescopes.
At absolute magnitude H=27.3, it's not very large, and at 10.5 times the lunar distance, it wasn't very close.

Gideon van Buitenen keeps a [list of near-Earth objects](http://astro.vanbuitenen.nl/brightneos)  (NEOs) which will appear brighter than magnitude 14 sometime in the next 12 months.
Naked-eye NEOs are quite rare.

Comment: @RobAdams For reference, in excellent conditions with good eyesight you might be able to see objects with apparent magnitudes of ~8 . Each point on the scale translates to a 2.5 change in brightness meaning that at app. mag.  21 the object is ~159,000 times less bright than the dimmest objects you can possibly see. so it's not even close.

Comment: @eps Magnitude 6 is a more realistic naked-eye limit.

Comment: yep, for sure -- most people don't have perfect eyesight observing the sky on a moonless night in the middle of absolute nowhere. I first wrote 6-8 but just decided to go with the best case scenario for simplicity.  Even 6 is probably not possible if you are in the limits of a big city.